# Approaches to wrapping ObjectContext implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am still new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Entity Framework. But I started contributing to an application using both frameworks and I got this (probably auto-generated) almighty `ObjectContext` implementation called `ModelContainer`. It cannot easily be mocked in a testing environment and it has a lot of methods and properties (so putting an interface etc. in front of it might not be the best idea).

For instance, it has a lot of these properties:

```
public ObjectSet<Company> Companies { \\ ... }
```

My idea now was to create a simple interface like this:

```
public interface IDB
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQueryableObjects<T>();
}
```

And create an adapter for the monstrosity:

```
public class ModelContainerDB : IDB
{
    private readonly ModelContainer _db;
    private static readonly Type _dbType = typeof(ModelContainer);

    public ModelContainerDB(ModelContainer db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryableObjects<T>()
    {
        var objectType = typeof (T);
        var queryableName = GetPropertyName(objectType.Name);
        var propertyInfo = _dbType.GetProperty(queryableName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        return (IQueryable<T>) propertyInfo.GetValue(_db, new object[0]);
    }

    private string GetPropertyName(string objectName)
    {
        if (objectName.EndsWith("y"))
            return objectName.Remove(objectName.Length - 1) + "ies";

        return objectName + "s";
    }
}
```

I know that reflection is slow but it is kind of nice in this scenario. So my questions are:

1. What are the downsides to this approach?
2. What could be improved?
3. What other approaches to my original problem of wrapping the `ObjectContext` implementation are there?

Comment: You could use `_db.CreateObjectSet<T>()`. If you need multiple calls to `GetQueryableObjects` to return the same object set instance, you could implement a simple cache.

Comment: A cache based on what? I only have `T`.

Comment: A cache based on `typeof(T)`. `GetQueryableObjects<ClassA>()` would then always return the same instance, and `GetQueryableObjects<ClassB>()` would return a different instance (as it has to).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a generic method which uses [`CreateObjectSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQueryableObjects<T>()
{       
    return _db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
}
```

Comment: You mean `CreateObjectSet`? Does that automatically retrieve `Users` for a class name `User`?

Comment: Oops, my bad.. Yes it does, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states: "Represents a typed entity set that is used to perform create, read, update, and delete operations.".